# How do I check if a structure has any entries at level 3 when I'm at level 1?

Tags: structure

I'd like to output a special link in level 1 upon current top-level entry doesn't have any entries at level 3. If It have move that special link one level above.

To picture it:

- Page 1

  - Subpage 1
  - Subpage 2
  - Special link A
- Page 2

  - Subpage 1

    - Subpage 1.1
    - Special link A

Currently I didn't have any difficulties with level 2:

```
{% set lvl = entry.level %} 
{% if lvl == 2 and entry.children|length %}
    A link
{% endif %}
```

To set that special link at level 1 is.
Most logical way to me is to use EntryModel's method `getDescendants( distance )` as I don't have to set any variable. If I understand it correctly It should get descendant entries at given level? of a current `entry`'s variable.  When I set to `(distance)` other integer than `1` let's say `2` It prints out all entries from second level including level 2. So It's unclear to me what `distance` does in this case.

```
{% if lvl == 1 and entry.getDescendants(2)|length %}
    A link
{% endif %}
```

Argument is true even if there are no descendant entries of second level. Because When looping in It prints all entries from second level up including second level as I mentioned before.

Or I can't use this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it works I had to query in the section for descendant entries at level 3 of a current `entry` variable.

```
{% set products = craft.entries.section('products') %}

{% if lvl == 1 and products.descendantOf(entry).level(3).first()|length %}
    // If the above statment is true we don't want that special link at level 1
{% elseif lvl == 1 %}
    // A special link
{% endif %}


{% if lvl == 2 and entry.children|length %}
    // A special link
{% endif %}
```

I welcome a smarter solution.

**Updated:** Thanks to @carlcs comment a performance has been enhanced

```
{% if lvl == 1 and products.descendantOf(entry).level(3).total() > 0 %}
    // If the above statment is true we don't want that special link at level 1
{% elseif lvl == 1 %}
    // A special link
{% endif %}


{% if lvl == 2 and entry.children.total() > 0 %}
    // A special link
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is a good solution, to improve performance you could just query for the amount of records in your conditionals `products.descendantOf(entry).level(3).total()` and `entry.children.total()`, as you’re not interested in the entry data at all.